# Google Maps API make icon a link

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for something to put in javascript that will enable me to click on the icon plotted on a Google maps API and it will send me to that page.

The plots are being read via an xml document and I would want it to link to that placeid

e.g

place.php?id=1233

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to do a redirect with `window.location` within the marker's click event callback function where the redirect link is in your example `place.php?id=1233`:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
 });
```